# How to Compile mingw-w64-crt

Tags: windows, gcc, compiler-errors, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm on Windows 10 and using the latest version of MSYS2 (with gcc installed: `pacman -S gcc`)

I'm trying to compile `mingw-w64-headers` and `mingw-w64-crt` from [mingw-w64-v7.0.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/)

Inside of my MSYS2 installation directory `C:\msys2` I have created the folder `mingw-w64` which I reference in the prefix argument below.

To compile each of these I use the same steps (replace name of library where appropriate):

```
mkdir mingw-w64-crt && cd mingw-w64-crt
../mingw-w64-v7.0.0/mingw-w64-crt/configure --prefix=/mingw-w64
make
make install
```

This works for `mingw-w64-headers` however for `mingw-w64-crt` I encounter errors at the `make` step. Specifically: *incompatible types when assigning to type '**mbstate_t**' {aka '**struct anonymous**'}* from type 'int'. A more detailed error image can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VusBI.jpg).

I would appreciate some guidance as to how to proceed.

Comment: This started off as a question about how to compile mingw-w64.  Please don't move the goalposts to something else (e.g. configuring GCC).  How about asking a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing the following has allowed me to successfully compile:

```
pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-toolchain
mkdir mingw-w64-crt && cd mingw-w64-crt
../mingw-w64-v7.0.0/mingw-w64-crt/configure --prefix=/mingw-w64 --with-sysroot=/mingw64
make -j %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you just open one of MSYS2's MinGW environments (by running mingw32.exe or mingw64.exe) and then install the complete MinGW-w64 toolchain by running this:

```
pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-toolchain
```

The toolchain includes GCC, the MinGW-w64 libraries, and the MinGW-w64 headers.  If those prebuilt MinGW-w64 things are good enough for you, then you're done.

If you want to compile your own MinGW-w64, then should be able to use the environment you just installed to do it.  To double-check that you are using the right toolchain, run `which gcc` and make sure it returns `/mingw64/bin/gcc` or `/mingw32/bin/gcc`.

Comment: I understand that pre-built toolchains exist, however I was hoping to compile myself so that I have debug information for my [non-gdb debugger](https://codeclap.itch.io/codeclap). Please see my edit above.

Comment: OK, but I think you were using the wrong toolchain to do that.  Please see my edited answer.