# How to Instruct mingw64-gcc to use Specific mingw-w64-headers/crt

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64, libc, compiler-flags, crt

I have compiled `mingw-w64-headers` and `mingw-w64-crt` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676291/how-to-compile-mingw-w64-crt/62687958#62687958).
My issue is how to get gcc to use them.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
SET mingw_dir=C:\msys64\mingw-w64

gcc -g -L %mingw_dir%\lib^
    -I %mingw_dir%\include^
    -Wl,--rpath=%mingw_dir%\lib^
    test.c -o test
```

It fails to compile giving:

*../lib/crt2.o:* in function **'pre_c_init'**:
*crt/crtexe.c:145:* undefined reference to **'__p__commode'**

This seems to be an issue with `ld`, however I'm not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that simply setting an environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH=C:\msys64\mingw-w64\lib;%LIBRARY_PATH%` solves the issue.

With this set, the command line invocation reduces to this:
`gcc -g test.c -o test`

Although this will use the headers installed by `pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-toolchain`, this simply means I just have to compile `mingw-w64-crt` to get debug information.